# Windows 10 JAVA_HOME environment variable ignored

Tags: java, windows-10, java-home

When I run `java -version` from the command line it returns `jre1.8.0_91`.  I've used setx from the command line and edited the environment variable for `JAVA_HOME`. The command line seem to be overridden or ignoring the environment variable. All JDK needing commands like mvn error with:  `"you must set JAVA_HOME to a jdk not a jre"`

`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241`

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` should only contain the path to a single JDK.

Answer (score 4):

JAVA_HOME should point to one directory only, you can't have two there. That's why your Maven does not work. Fix that and Maven should work.

`java -version` output is not directly related, that command does not use JAVA_HOME but PATH (but as noted in the comments, it is *possible* that PATH refers to JAVA_HOME, so in that case they are indirectly related).

Comment: It is normal practice though to prepend `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` to your `PATH`

Comment: I do not have a jre 11 installed. I removed the jdk1.8.0_241 entry path and got the same error, then removed jdk11 entry path and replace the previous and it worked as expected. Not sure if this would have worked  with jdk11 if the jre was also installed.   Running java -version does reflect updated _241 build

Comment: @g00se yes, but usually there is something with java already in PATH before that one

Comment: @Sherum maybe you removed it wrong. Did you remember to remove `;` also from JAVA_HOME value?

Comment: *@g00se yes, but usually there is something with java already in PATH before that one* @ais You need to read my comment more carefully, in particular the 7th word ;)

Comment: @g00se ok, misread prepend as append. I think it is more common to append it rather than prepend. If it is added at the beginning then you're right that it matters.

Comment: @eis Yes. I specifically said that for the reason *you* gave

Comment: I reconfigured for jdk 11 using setx and   mvn worked correctly. i cannot be certain if I had a trailing ; causing the issue.

Comment: @Sherum if you consider this answer has resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer (the tick box beside the answer)